# Allow meaningful titles for starred one-boxed chat messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

For certain websites, chat automatically one-boxes the content when writing a chat message that only contains a link. This displays a short summary inline in the chat room, instead of only showing the link. This is especially useful for something like Twitter, where the whole content fits into the one-box.

A major disadvantage is that starring those one-boxed messages is rather useless, the star board will only show the raw link. So you have to follow each one to know what it is actually about.

As far as I know, there is also no possible workaround for this. We can either manually add a meaningful title and prevent the one-box, or the other way around, there is no way to have both.

Ideally, the star board would show the extracted text for all one-boxed content, as that is much more meaningful and useful than the raw link. I'm not entirely sure how all this works behind the scenes, so I'll stay rather vague on the implementation details.

Comment: Good idea, but I doubt whether it will be implemented any time soon.